# Check if pip is installed on Windows using python subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, intellij-idea, subprocess

I am using python to check whether pip is installed on the system or not.
The code I have written is :

```
subprocess.run(["pip"],shell=True)
```

and I am getting the following error:

> 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I have tried passing my system env to run using

```
env = os.environ.copy()
subprocess.run(["pip"],shell=True,env=env)
```

but still no luck.
I installed pip on my Windows machine using get-pip.py

Answer (score 0):

If `CreateProcess` (that `subproces.run` invokes) does not recognize pip as a command, it may recognize python? So you could do: `subprocess.run(['python3', '-m', 'pip'])` maybe?

Comment: Thanks @Alper. I have just realized that my commands are not working in the IntelliJ ide, but are working in cmd. Even your command works in cmd. Is there something I can do so that i can see the result in IDE ?

Comment: Depends on what kind of environment IntelliJ runs this in. I don't have a copy lying around.'

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the path of your pip installation to your PATH system variable. Type echo $PATH$ to check if it already there or not.

Comment: Nothing is there on PATH. I had setup PATH variables manually by going to System>Environment Variables and editing and adding. python is there on the but even that is not showing up when I echo $PATH$. I am able to call pip and python on cmd.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, `pip` will not necessarily be in the `PATH` environment variable, so a simple run of `pip` may not find it.

If `pip` is installed in the currently running Python, you should be able to import its module:

```
pip_present = True
try:
    import pip
except ImportError:
    pip_present = False
```

If you want to run it using `subprocess`, you can get its usual location relative to the currently running Python using things in `sys`:

```
pip_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable), "Scripts", "pip.exe")
subprocess.run([pip_path])
```

Comment: I wonder if there's a more canonical way to get the path of the current interpreter's Python bin/Scripts directory (as the name is OS-dependent.)

Comment: I think you can get interpreter path with `sys.executable` with sys imported.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the return code of the command as such:

```
import sys
import subprocess

def pip_installed():
    pip_check = subprocess.run([sys.executable, "-m", "pip"])
    return not bool(pip_check.returncode)
```

This will check the returncode.
If returncode is 0, that means pip is installed and will return `True`
For any other value it will return `False`